# Why, when creating an app, do name examples include HRforce and Bugforce when the Salesforce Brand guidelines forbid to use names with 'Force' in it?

Tags: appexchange, package, app

Why, when creating an app, do name examples include HRforce, Financeforce and Bugforce when the Salesforce Brand guidelines forbid to ever use names with 'Force' in it?

[image]

Or is there a slight difference between Appname and Productname that I do not understand?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A custom app in Salesforce is not the same thing as an AppExchange app. A [custom app](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dev_tabsets.htm&language=en_US) is:

> An “app” is a group of tabs that works as a unit to provide
>   application functionality. Salesforce provides standard apps such as
>   Sales and Call Center. You can customize the standard apps to match
>   the way you work.

So, essentially, a custom app is just a collection of tabs.

What gets sold on the AppExchange is a [managed package](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=managing_packages.htm&language=en_US):

> Packages are a collection of Force.com components and applications
>   that are made available to other organizations through the
>   AppExchange. A managed package is a collection of application
>   components that are posted as a unit on AppExchange, and are
>   associated with a namespace and a License Management Organization.

As you can see, these are completely different things. A [managed package](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sharing_apps.htm&language=en) is a collection of a bunch of different things (Apex classes, Visualforce pages, Custom Objects, etc), while a custom app is only a collection of tabs.

While it may be a bit confusing and they most likely could have chosen better examples, most custom apps are never sold on the AppExchange. If you aren't trying to sell an application, "HRforce", "Financeforce" and "Bugforce" are all perfectly valid custom app names. It is just the name that will be displayed in the top right hand corner.

[image: HRforce]

Comment: Hmm, yes, so the only problem here is that Salesforce suggests us to use appneams that in the end are not allowed when actually packaged and published on the AppExchange.

Is that why e.g. FinancialForce slipped? Or do they have an exclusive position where they are allowed to use the Force name but the rest of the world isn't?

Comment: @WillemMulder Basically, the examples they chose simply aren't good managed package names. A majority of custom apps will never be part of a managed package, so I understand why they chose them, but they are poor examples for a managed package.

Comment: Indeed. Do you by any chance know why FinancialForce can have their name? Since that is a published package but still has the Force part in it?

Comment: @WillemMulder I can't comment on that to be honest. I don't know exactly why FinancialForce is allowed to have Force in the name. Anything I would say would be speculation.